# Convert an a0 post to an a2 poster

Tags: posters, a0poster

I have found a very nice template for an a0 poster (see http://www.latextemplates.com/template/a0poster-landscape-poster), I however need to make a poster of a2 size. How would I go about converting the poster to a2 size? I have tried changing the

```
\documentclass[a0,landscape]{a0poster}
```

to

```
\documentclass[a2,landscape]{a0poster}
```

However the columns are too wide. How do I change the width of these? There seems to be nothing in the code that specifies their width.

Comment: Looking at the sample, you apparently control the column widths with `multicol` as usual.

Comment: The A series are all in the same aspect ratio so you don't need to do anything. You can produce it at A0 and then just scale to A2 when printing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my suggestion.

Leave the line

```
\documentclass[a0,landscape]{a0poster}
```

as it is and add the following lines

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{resize and center}
{
  \def\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=1,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5215\pgfphysicalwidth}{.47\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize and center}[a2paper,landscape]
```

just after the line

```
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
```

In this way you will have the same document as before, but with `a2 landscape` size.

Output:

[image]

and these are the properties of the `pdf` file as shown by the viewer

[image]

that is to say `a2 landscape`.

Note that the new layout `resize and center` is obtained from the standard `resize to` with some adjusting to the center point, so to obtain the right positioning of the poster.

Comment: Great answer. It appears however that the layout goes a bit awry, i.e. with the a2 result, the poster is not centred, there is some whitespace at the bottom and on the right hand side. Any ideas how to sort this?

Comment: @rossi_182 I've updated the answer. Now it should be perfect...

Comment: By the way, I have already downloaded this zip file but when I try to run it I found an error. Second how to change a text color? Thank's

Comment: @Zbigniew I don't get any error. To change the color, put `\color{yourcolor}`. Ask a follow-up question if this is not enough.

Comment: @karlkoeller Is it possible to do such resizing for A1 size landscape poster? If yes, then what should be center = \pgfpoint{.5215\pgfphysicalwidth}{.47\pgfphysicalheight} values?